# Laravel eloquent doesn't insert data when bug occur during multiple insert

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent, batch-insert

I'm trying to insert users using csv.
My model has an observer on "created" event.

However I can have a bug after some $users->save() because of code in my function created event (which I fixed).

The code in created event send an email to the user. The problem is if code crash after 5iterations, I got my 5emails send but no user in my db.

I'm wondering if Eloquent use transaction when you call multiple times save() ?
If yes how to force Eloquent to really save my object after each end of event created ?

May be I'm misunderstanding something with event, because I don't see the point of using this event if your not sure to have your model insert in your DB.

Comment: You might want to do the saves and email sends in separate steps. A transaction, if wrapping multiple calls to `->save()`, will prevent any of those saves from persisting if any one of them fails (and you have the code configured to handle that). You might not be able to use an observer in this case though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however what I'm not understanding is why Eloquent seems to use transaction. 
I'm not the original owner of this project so maybe I'm missing something with eloquent configuration or documentation.

Comment: Oh I see! By default, Laravel and Eloquent do not use transactions; if you have a series of calls to `->save()`, they _will_ be persisted, one by one by one. Check your code for any calls to `DB::beginTransaction()`, as that's how you typically set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what was wrong...

To insert csv my project use :
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

And after some research, this is "why" eloquent use transaction in my case :
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#database-transactions